# "failed to create process." error when converting QtDesigner file to .py using pyside-uic

Tags: python, pyside, qt-designer

I type this into powershell:

```
pyside-uic.exe login.ui -o login.py
```

Then i get the error message: failed to create process.

How do i fix this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

figured out how to fix this.
Just set pyside-uic.exe to run as administrator.